# How to build automation test for Webservice api that's independence with Database

Tags: testing, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd

I'm new with automation test term. Currently I had a project which would like to apply Cucumber to test Rest Api. But when i try to assert out put of endpoints of this api base on current data, so I wonder what happen if I changed environment or there are any change in test database in the future, so my test case will be potential to fail.

What is the best practice to write test which's independence on database.

Or I need to run my test with empty separated db and execute some script to initialize db before to run test?

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is not clear to me. Can you re-iterate? what does " But when i try to assert out put of endpoints of this api base on current data" mean?

Comment: Sure. Example i have endpoints: getproduct?type=car. So I need to asssert to make sure  i got all car. But number of car belong to current database. It’s be able to be changed in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to assert the response value that comes (eg:number of cars) it is actually impossible to make it database independent. I guess you can understand why? What I would do in a similar situation is something like this.

- Use the API and get the number of cars in the database (eg: 544) and assign it to a variable.
- Using the API add another car to the database.
- Then again check the total cars in the database and assert (should be 544 + 1 else fail)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your tests to be trustworthy, they should not depend on the test data being in the database or not. You should be in control of that data. So in order to make it independent of the current state of the database: insert the expected data as a precondition (setup) of your test. (And delete it again at the end of the test). If the database connection is not actually part of your test, you could also stub or mock the result from the database (this will make your tests faster, as you're not using db connectivity).